# How to convert a txt stream web request containing json to a jObject?

Tags: c#, .net, json, stream, streamreader

Trying to use a query Google has available, but they return an attached txt file containing the JSON results. I'm a newbie programmer, so I can't figure out why any of the shots I took aren't working.

```
    public async Task<YouTubeSearchResult> SearchYouTubeAsync(string query)
    {
        var result = new YouTubeSearchResult();
        string errorMessage = "";
        try
        {
            string encodedName = WebUtility.UrlEncode(query);
            Uri url = new Uri($"http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q={encodedName}");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Stream streamResult = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamResult);

            errorMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd());
            JObject jsonResults = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd()));

            result.Success = true;
            result.Message = "Success getting search results";
            result.SearchResults = jsonResults;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Success = false;
            result.Message = $"Server error getting search results: {errorMessage} | {ex}";
            result.SearchResults = null;
        }

        return result;

    }
}
```

This is the response along with the error code I get.

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "Server error getting search results: \"[\"search\",[\"search\",\"search and destroy\",\"searching for my baby bobby moore\",\"search engine optimization\",\"search and discard\",\"search for the worst\",\"search youtube\",\"searching\",\"search history\",\"search party sam bruno\"]]\" | Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '', line 1, position 2.\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)\r\n   at OdsCode.Services.YouTubeSearchService.<SearchYouTubeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()",
  "searchResults": null
}
```

Adding the error and current results separately to clarify.

> | Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from
>   JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '',
>   line 1, position 2.\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings
>   settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json,
>   JsonLoadSettings settings)\r\n   at
>   OdsCode.Services.YouTubeSearchService.d__3.MoveNext()",
>
> "Server error getting search results:
>   \"[\"search\",[\"search\",\"search and destroy\",\"searching for my
>   baby bobby moore\",\"search and discard\",\"search for the
>   worst\",\"search youtube\",\"search engine
>   optimization\",\"searching\",\"search history\",\"search party sam
>   bruno\"]]\" |

Below is the response I get from google in postman

```
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q=search

Cache-Control →no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition →attachment; filename="f.txt"
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →136
Content-Type →text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date →Wed, 19 Oct 2016 20:10:17 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
Server →gws
X-Frame-O

ptions →SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block

[
  "search",
  [
    "search",
    "search and destroy",
    "searching for my baby bobby moore",
    "search engine optimization",
    "search and discard",
    "search for the worst",
    "search youtube",
    "searching",
    "search history",
    "search party sam bruno"
  ]
]
```

Help me I been at it for days now... No food until I figure this out!!!!!

Comment: You are the receiving end. Don't use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. `JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd())` is all. (object2json -> serialization & json2object -> deserialization)

Comment: I get the following when I take it off → Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)\r\n   at OdsCode.Services.YouTubeSearchService.<SearchYouTubeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem one - you use `reader.ReadToEnd()` twice. First when you attempt to read errorMessage, Then on the next line you use it again. By the second time you have already read everything.
Delete the line:

```
errorMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Problem two - looks like the data you are receiving is an array so in order to read it you will need to use

```
JArray jsonResults = JArray.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
```